# Почему начальная дата не сегодня?

Tags: javascript, jquery

а 2000 год

```js
function dateTravel(dFrom, dTo) {

        if($(dFrom).length && $(dTo).length) {

            $(dFrom).datepicker({
                prevText: '<i class="icon-arrow_left"></i>',
                nextText: '<i class="icon-arrow_right"></i>',
                minDate: 0,
                dateFormat: 'dd.mm.yy',
                onSelect: function () {
                    let minDate = $(this).datepicker('getDate');
                    setTimeout(function () {
                         minDate.setDate(minDate.getDate() + 1);
                        $(dTo).datepicker('option', 'minDate', minDate);
                    }, 300);
                }
            }).datepicker('setDate', '0');

            $(dTo).datepicker({
                prevText: '<i class="icon-arrow_left"></i>',
                nextText: '<i class="icon-arrow_right"></i>',
                minDate: 1,
                dateFormat: 'dd.mm.yy',
            }).datepicker('setDate', '1');
        }

    }

    dateTravel('#edit-date_from', '#edit-date_to');
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/datepicker/1.0.10/datepicker.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<input type="text" value="" id="edit-date_from" class="full" readonly>

 <input type="text" value="" id="edit-date_to" class="full" readonly>
 
 <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/datepicker/1.0.10/datepicker.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: у меня начальная дата с вашего кода 05/24/2022

Comment: Тот же результат и у меня

Comment: А почему должна быть сегодня?

Answer (score 0):

Если я правильно понял, что требуется. `datepicker('setDate', 'today');` устанавливает текущую дату. `new Date().setFullYear(new Date().getFullYear() + 1))` - следующий год

```js
function dateTravel(dFrom, dTo) {

        if($(dFrom).length && $(dTo).length) {

            $(dFrom).datepicker({
                prevText: '<i class="icon-arrow_left"></i>',
                nextText: '<i class="icon-arrow_right"></i>',
                minDate: 0,
                dateFormat: 'dd.mm.yy',
                onSelect: function () {
                    let minDate = $(this).datepicker('getDate');
                    setTimeout(function () {
                         minDate.setDate(minDate.getDate() + 1);
                        $(dTo).datepicker('option', 'minDate', minDate);
                    }, 300);
                }
            }).datepicker('setDate', 'today');

         

            $(dTo).datepicker({
                prevText: '<i class="icon-arrow_left"></i>',
                nextText: '<i class="icon-arrow_right"></i>',
                minDate: 1,
                dateFormat: 'dd.mm.yy',
            }).datepicker('setDate', new Date(new Date().setFullYear(new Date().getFullYear() + 1)));
        }

    }

    dateTravel('#edit-date_from', '#edit-date_to');
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/datepicker/1.0.10/datepicker.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<input type="text" value="" id="edit-date_from" class="full" readonly>

 <input type="text" value="" id="edit-date_to" class="full" readonly>
 
 <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/datepicker/1.0.10/datepicker.min.js"></script>
```